# How to improve query performance in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, jpa

I am using Oracle 11G in my application.

Here in my database there is a table MST_PRODUCT which contains 80 00 000 of records.

As per the requirement, I am using  JPA native query to retrieve data from the table.

EX :

```
     SELECT sku_id
FROM MST_PRODUCT prod
WHERE brand_code IN
  (
   SELECT brand_code
   FROM MST_PRODUCT prod
   WHERE prod.SKU_ID IN
   (SELECT prd_value FROM TRANS_SCH_UNIT_PRD_SCOPE TSUPS WHERE TSUPS.sch_id='600')
  ) and prod.sku_id NOT IN
  (SELECT prd_value
  FROM TRANS_SCH_UNIT_PRD_SCOPE TSUPS
  WHERE TSUPS.sch_id='600'
  );
```

The above mentioned query is taking too much time to retrieve data.

Approximately there are 80 00 000 SKU IDs and 500 Brand Code  in the table.

This query is taking 50 to 60 seconds to complete execution. Sometimes more than that.

And here is the scheme of my table...

```
CREATE TABLE "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" 
   (    "PRD_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COMPANY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LOB" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PRD_DEPT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PRD_SUB_DEPT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CLASS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SUB_CLASS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MC_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "BRAND_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SKU_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MC_DESC" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SKU_DESC" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "BRAND_DESC" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "MODIFIED_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "CREATED_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "IS_ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
     CONSTRAINT "MST_PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PRD_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."BRAND_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("BRAND_CODE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."CLASS_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("CLASS") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."COMP_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("COMPANY") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."DEPT_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("PRD_DEPT") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."MST_PRD_ISACTIVE_IDX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("IS_ACTIVE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."MST_PRD_MCCODE_IDX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("MC_CODE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT_INDEX1" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("LOB") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT_PK" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("PRD_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."SKU_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("SKU_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."SUBCLASS_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("SUB_CLASS") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "PERK"."SUB_INDEX" ON "PERK"."MST_PRODUCT" ("PRD_SUB_DEPT") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

And here is the execution plan of the query...

[image]

Can anyone suggest me, How can I improve this query ? OR What factor I need to take care while preparing a query ?

Reagrds,
Gunjan.

Comment: Have you tried indexes for you columns.You can also see the explain plan to understand the running of the query.

Comment: almost sure he has an index on brand_code.

Comment: Post the execution plan and the definition of the indexes defined for the table.

Comment: Have given execution plan details and index details. pls check it

Answer (score 0):

I would try using joins instead of sub-selects.  Sub-selects generally perform worse than joins.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
Select Sku_Id
  From Mst_Product Prod
 Where Exists (Select Null
          From Mst_Product Iprod, Trans_Sch_Unit_Prd_Scope Tsups
         Where Prod.Brand_Code = Iprod.Brand_Code
           And Iprod.Sku_Id = Tsups.Prd_Value
           And Tsups.Sch_Id = '600')
   And Not Exists (Select Null
          From Trans_Sch_Unit_Prd_Scope Tsups
         Where Tsups.Sch_Id = '600'
           And Prod.Sku_Id = Tsups.Prd_Value);
```